# is there any way to use special functions with rasters?

Tags: python, scipy, arcgis

```
>>> dd=special.kv(0,Raster("adiff_C1.tif"))
 Runtime error <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: ufunc 'kv' not supported for the input        types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the  casting rule 'safe'
```

python 2.6
scipy-0.7.1-win32-superpack-python2.6
numpy-1.6.1-win32-superpack-python2.6
ARCGIS 10

Comment: Please formulate a nice question, there is no possible way to understand what's happening. Add what's happening and what you are looking to do. This way people can aid you easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to [convert your Raster object to a numpy array](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000012z000000).  Then `scipy.special.kv` will work fine:

```
In [9]: x = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

In [10]: x
Out[10]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])

In [11]: special.kv(0, x)
Out[11]: 
array([[ 0.42102444,  0.11389387,  0.0347395 ],
       [ 0.01115968,  0.0036911 ,  0.00124399]])
```